# Optimal way to replace ObservableCollection item when user click on databound CollectionView item

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, collections, time-complexity

i'm a newbie with Xamarin forms DataBinding and ObservableCollections.

My question is about being notified when i replace an item in ObservableCollection. Let me tell you about my goal. First, a little be of problem context:

- ObservableCollection is on a viemModel, for example ObservableCollection<"Customer">.
- The collection is Bind to a Xamarin CollectionView, showing some Customer info and a button to update Customer status.
- In response to Button click event I use Rest services and to do a Post for updating the clicked customer.
- Post method return a new item: the modified Customer

At this point, i wonder the best way to update collection so my user interface is refreshed.

I know i can update  properties on Item but to get this way working i must implement INotifyPropertyChange on my Customer (POCO object). It's not a problem, but sometimes there is a lot of properties updated by Rest service and i would prefer to replace the edited customer in ObservableCollection with the new one returned by Post method and not updating properties one by one.

So, i replace the object on collection with this code, and is working fine:

```
var index = viewModel.Items.IndexOf(originalCustomer);
viewModel.Items[index] = updatedCustomer;
```

But this way involve to get the index of item to be replaced using Collection.IndexOf(customer) and that's seems to be an O(n) operation. **¿There is any way to get the index of clicked customer directly on click event with O(1) complexity?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> But this way involve to get the index of item to be replaced using Collection.IndexOf(customer) and that's seems to be an O(n) operation. ¿There is any way to get the index of clicked customer directly on click event with O(1) complexity?

If you want to get current index in Button click event, I suggest you can bind Collectionview SelectedItem, then you can get this index when you change selecteditem. Please confire that you set SelectedMode=Single.

I create simple for you, please take a look:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView
            ItemsSource="{Binding customers}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding selecteditem}"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Age}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="Get Index" />
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page2 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<customer> customers { get; set; }
    private customer _selecteditem;
    public customer selecteditem
    {
        get { return _selecteditem; }
        set
        {
            _selecteditem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selecteditem");
        }
    }
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        customers = new ObservableCollection<customer>()
        {
            new customer(){Name="cherry",Age=28},
            new customer(){Name="Wendy",Age=28},
            new customer(){Name="Jessie",Age=28},
            new customer(){Name="Barry",Age=28},
            new customer(){Name="Jason",Age=28},
            new customer(){Name="Annine",Age=28},
            new customer(){Name="Jack",Age=28},
            new customer(){Name="Leo",Age=28},
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;

    }

    private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var index = customers.IndexOf(selecteditem);
        Console.WriteLine("Current index is {0}",index);
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But in Button click event i can get the clicked item through Button BindingContext, so, i don't need a binding to SelectedItem property. Anyway You use customer.IndexOf(item) to get the item index and that's my question: ¿There is any way to get de index of clicked item without using indexOf, (in a O(1) way)?

Comment: @Fran, If you want to get item index directly, don't use indexof(item), I suggest you can try to add one int type property in Customer class as **ID**, as CollectionView selectedindex, so you can get Id from Item.